# Can't create zombie process

Tags: c, windows, process, zombie-process

[image]

I'm trying to create a zombie process in C using this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

void main()
{
        int pid;
        pid=fork(); /* Duplicate */
        if (pid!=0) /* Branch based on return value from fork() */
        {
                while (1) /* never terminate, and never execute a wait()*/
                sleep(1000);
        }
        else
        {
                exit(42); /* Exit with a silly number */
        }
}
```

Problem is I only know how to check if a zombie process exists only in bash. So I used the Bash on windows feature available in windows 10. I created an executable file for the above code and ran it in background And checked for a zombie process  but couldn't find it. I repeated the same steps in an Ubuntu running PC and it worked. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Windows isn't UNIX.

Comment: What are you **really** trying to accomplish?

Comment: @IInspectable It was just an assignement given to us at college. To create a  zombie process. I successfully did that at my college's computer lab which runs Ubuntu. But can't understand why am I not getting the same results for Bash on Windows

Comment: The *Windows Subsystem for Linux* is a beta. And even when it goes RTM, you should expect differences in behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Windows does not have zombie processes.

Zombies are a peculiarity of the Unix process model -- when a process exits (in UNIX) its exit status isn't sent anywhere.  Instead, it just sits around until some other process queries the exit status.  The zombie process state allows for this -- after a process exits, it remains a zombie until someone (anyone) queries its exit status.

On Windows, on the other hand, when a process is created with CreateProcess, you specify where the exit status info should be sent when it exits (generally back to its parent, but could be elsewhere).  So when a process exits, the data is sent there immediately with no intervention from anywhere.  There's nothing and no place for other processes to query for exit status.

If you are using a UNIX emulator (such as cygwin) on Windows, then you may get zombies of a form -- generally the emulator will have a data structure tracking extra UNIX-style process information somewhere, and that data structure will likely contain a place to hold exit status where it can be queried after the process has exited, just like a zombie.

Comment: Note that only the parent process can get the zombie status.  There's a special rule that if a zombie's parent dies without waiting for the zombie, then a special system process inherits the zombie.  The special process's prime purpose in life is to wait for processes to die — slaying the evil zombies.

Comment: Bash on Windows *is* a Unix emulator. I've never seen it run, but from what I've read, it's good enough to run Ubuntu, which should mean that it's accurate enough to emulate zombie processes.

Comment: @Gilles: It's not an emulator. It's an implementation.

Comment: This answer is complete bogus. A call to `CreateProcess` does exactly what the function name implies. It creates a process and returns a handle to the caller. As long as there are open handles to the process object, you can query it's exit code. The exit code can be queried by anyone holding a handle to the process. It doesn't have to be the caller of `CreateProcess`. I'm going to assume that you have the dignity to delete this not-even-an-answer-to-another-question.